# How to change src value in <embed> while cloning whole <div> with js?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new at web based applications and want to ask a question regarding cloning a whole div. What i want to do is: Change value of src after it's cloned. There is a function for it but it's not working after I added cloning function.

```
<div id="ytContainer0">
    <embed id="ytsrc" width="800" height="500"
        src="https://www.youtube.com/v/CrHsXTqbwkM" />
</div>

<input id="input" type="text" name="Youtube Source" />
<button id="button" onclick="changeLink();">Click to change source!</button>

<script>
document.getElementById('button').onclick = duplicate;
var i = 0;
function duplicate() {
    var original = document.getElementById('ytContainer' + i);
    var clone = original.cloneNode(true);
    clone.id = "ytContainer" + ++i;
    clone.onclick = duplicate;
    original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
}
</script>

<script>
function changeLink() {
    var link = document.getElementById("ytsrc");
    ytsrc.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/v/' + input.value;
    return false;
}
</script>
```

On jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4dat1n11/2/

Comment: Post your code in your question, not in a link.

Comment: what does it even change, code is a code. but if that's how this website rolls, I will do it.

Comment: Btw why does this have 2 downvotes? For that jsfiddle link?

Comment: Yes, this is how the site works. You can [read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Perhaps that's the reason for the downvotes. Don't worry about them, once you edit your question to be considered a good one, there will be more upvotes. The jsfiddle link was good, put it back. You need both the code and the link. Welcome to SO.

Comment: I added that jsfiddle link.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you wan to do exactly, but your code has many issues:

- Your button's `onclick` is assigned `changeLink()` in HTML, but then your first line in JavaScript `document.getElementById('button').onclick = duplicate` is overwriting it, so effectively the function `changeLink()` is never called.
- You're cloning the `div` container and assigning it a new ID, but you also need to assign a new ID to the `embed` otherwise you end up with several `embed` sharing the same ID.
- You assign the `duplicate()` function to the new clone, which is supposed to display a video inside, but the video need to be clicked to play which means the `onclick` on the clone is not going to be ever fired.
- You probably need to delete the `changeLink()` function and call the `duplicate()` function directly. In this case, you need to change the `src` there.

Here is a working example:

```js
var i = 0;
function duplicate() {
    var original = document.getElementById('ytContainer' + i);
    var clone = original.cloneNode(true);
    clone.id = "ytContainer" + ++i;
    embed = clone.children[0];
    embed.id = 'ytsrc' + i;
    embed.src = 'https://www.youtube.com/v/' + input.value;
    original.parentNode.appendChild(clone);
}
```

```html
<div id="ytContainer0">
    <embed id="ytsrc" width="800" height="500"
        src="https://www.youtube.com/v/CrHsXTqbwkM" />
</div>

<input id="input" type="text" name="Youtube Source" />
<button id="button" onclick="duplicate();">Click to change source!</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me out. It works as I needed.
I did it with 2 buttons because as you said, document.getElementById('button').onclick = duplicate was overwriting it. But now i can do it with one button.
Thanks again.